# Cordova ios-The default Firebase app has not yet been configured

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication cordova plugin to integrate firebase sign in in my cordova ios application. So I searched google and found GoogleService-Info.plist is missing in platfor/ios/app/Resources folder. I have downloaded the file in the same folder and also copied the file in xcode still the application is throwing `[Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add`[FIRApp configure];`(`FirebaseApp.configure()`in Swift) to your application initialization` Can some one help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file GoogleService-Info.plist should not be created manually. Instead, you download this file from Firebase Console, after you can a project and an ios app inside this project. Do not forget to place the file with the root of your Cordova app

Comment: Yes I downloaded my GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase console and place in cordova root, projects and projects/projects

Comment: Did you place it in the same level where you have config.xml file?

Comment: The other part of this puzzle is that it's not sufficient to add the config.xml lines and place the .plist file in the root directory -- you need to do a "cordova platform remove ios" and a "cordova platform add ios". Elsewhere I read it was sufficient to do a "cordova platform prepare ios" but that failed for me with the same error OP notes.